# Having some trouble with php mail on localhost with XAMPP

Tags: javascript, php, xampp, localhost

I'm trying to work locally so I installed XAMPP and need help resolving an issue while sending mail via a php script on localhost. I've tested everything on a web-facing server and it works fine.

I'm getting the error 'Cannot POST /php/mail.php' from http://localhost:3000/php/mail.php.

I've changed the php.ini and sendmail.ini files and believe they are correctly configured for it to work.

Getting some errors in the DevTools console related to inline scripts but I think they are related to the error page.

Is there somewhere else I can look to debug this error?

Comment: This is the wrong platform for this sort of question. Here you ask very specific questions and get specific answers. It's not for guided problem solving.

Comment: I can't post images (not enough points) and I don't believe the problem to be in the code itself.  So instead of asking for an answer that I know is to a very general question, I asked where I could begin looking myself.  Apologies if this isn't correct.

Comment: That's a good way to solve this problem but Stackoverflow is probably the wrong platform for this.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks Thomas.